# Why uint foo = 5, foo/=6 work, but not foo = 5/6?

Tags: solidity, evm

I'm writing a contract that evaluates (foo/x)*x to give equivalent of math.floor(foo/x)*x. It works, but if I hard code numbers instead (I don't need to do that, just interested), (5/6)*5, it is not allowed in Remix. What is the rationale for that? I'm mostly asking to know if using (foo/x)*x is a bit of a hack, or if the language supports that intentionally (if it does, just don't see why (5/6)*5 is not allowed.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `5 / 6` is interpreted by the compiler as a rational constant (`fixed` or `ufixed`).

Therefore, such constant value cannot be assigned to an integer variable (`uint` or `int`).

On the other hand, when you do:

```
uint x = 5;
x /= 6;
```

The compiler replaces the `/` operation with the opcode for integer division, which is perfectly valid.

You can read more about fixed-point numbers in [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.12/types.html?highlight=ufixed#fixed-point-numbers).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I did not know functionality to interpret as non-integers/fraction was there. But since it is, perfectly understandable.

Comment: It looks like it is allowed prior to 0.3.3, and the changelog here says fractional/rational constants were added then, https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md. I started writing Solidity contracts before 0.3.3, and I assumed fractions were still not allowed, which is why I could not understand :)

Comment: @Johan: Wow, before 0.4? You must be one of the earliest adapters in the eco-system!

Comment: I was early. But still not good at the computer science aspects :) I self-describe as specialized in social coordination system design.